# Raspberry Pi Over the Air Update

Tags: python

I have a raspberry pi and it is connected to a server. Realistically, I will have multiple pi's and a server. I will need to push an updated file to the pi from the server. My question is, is an update just deleting an old copy of the code and downloading the new copy? As well, what is the best of implementing this over the air update?

Comment: This question is not on topic as is defined in the help center since it has nothing to do with the RPi specifically.

http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 1):

You can use your own repository or just use your own update script with rsync or git. Look into the 3 listed options then ask more specific questions.